# SEM, path analysis without latent variables

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation

If the mediation analysis includes only observed variables, would it be necessary to test the measurement model and conduct a CFA prior to path analyses?

Are there other analyses, on top of assumptions, that are advised to be conducted before the path analysis itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is, why would you run your path analysis with only observed variables if you *could* set up a measurement model (CFA) with multiple indicators? Wouldn't it be better to then also run the path analysis based on latent variables (factors) to correct for measurement error? It seems inconsistent to me to first run a CFA/test a measurement model with multiple indicators and then use only observed variables for the structural (mediation/path) model.

I would recommend the usual checks such as for outliers, (approximate) normality, linearity, etc. that are commonly conducted for continuous variables prior to the main analyses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you make a compelling argument. Are the variables in the model usually treated as latent even when they are based on established, validated scales?

Comment: "Latent" in the context of SEM simply means "corrected for measurement error." Unless your validated scales show perfect reliabilities (1.0), there will be some measurement error involved. This can be addressed by running your model as a latent path analysis, in which true score ("latent") variance is separated from measurement error variance.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!